# Why is dump_stack() function empty in linux kernel 5.14.0?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to learn about linux kernel module development, and I see in several resources the use of `dump_stack` defined in `linux/printk.h`. I tried it, and it doesn't do anything, so I go to look in the header files included with linux 5.14 (`linux-5.14/include/linux/printk.h`) and I see the definition is

```c
static inline void dump_stack(void)
{
}
```

Thinking I must have done something wrong getting the source, I check the header files included with the distribution of linux I am using (kali linux) in `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.14.0-kali2-common/include/linux/printk.h` and I see the same thing. What am I missing here?

Comment: There are **two declarations** of `dump_stack`, selected depending on the macro `CONFIG_PRINTK`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.20/source/include/linux/printk.h#L167. The one you show is applied when the macro is not defined. As you could guess, undefined macro `CONFIG_PRINTK` means that `printk` functionality is disabled (`printk` does nothing). The other declaration of `dump_stack` is at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.20/source/include/linux/printk.h#L211. And corresponding definition is at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.20/source/lib/dump_stack.c#L110

Comment: *"I tried it, and it doesn't do anything"* - how did you try it? Show us a [mre].